# Trying to solve for x when you have sine and cosine in the function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, graphing-functions

Graph $f(x) = \sin (x^2)$

I need to graph $f(x) = \sin (x^2)$ from $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$ and from that, I need to include the first derivative which is set to zero and used to find the maximum and minimum.
That I totally get however then I need to go and find the second derivative and set equal to zero and find any points of inflection. (Basically, find 2nd derivative, set equal to zero, and find $x$)
However the second derivative I found is $2\cos(x^2) - 4x^2 \sin(x^2)$ and because of the cosine and sine, I have no idea how to solve for $x$.
Any help will be deeply appreciated. Just to be clear, I'm having problems trying to solve for $x$ in the second derivative.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: There's not going to be an exact solution for the points of inflection.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question down correctly? If it was:$$f(x)=\sin^2(x)$$Then everything works out much better.

Comment: Sadly it was what I have written. I wish though!

Comment: @John $z = \frac12 \cot z$ with the substitution $z=x^2$ is the nicest you can get for numerical solutions I suppose. Ultimately, the distance between two such $z$ should converge to $\pi$ due to the periodicity of $\cot$.

Comment: @AlexR Okay, thank you for your help. I am deeply thankful for you taking a stab at it!

Answer (score 1):

We can do a few simplifications: Substitute $z=x^2$ so $x = \pm\sqrt z$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
2\cos x^2 - 4x^2 \sin x^2 & = 0\\
\Leftrightarrow \cos z - 2z\sin z & = 0 & z \ge 0
\end{align*} $$
Now since $z=0$ is no solution and $\cos z = 0 \Rightarrow \sin z \ne 0$ is also no solution, we can divide by $\cos z$ and get
$$1 = 2z\tan z$$
so
$$z = \frac12 \cot z$$
The solutions for the latter [seem symbolically intangible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+cot%28z%29%2F2), but we can use the numerical results to obtain numerical results for $x = \pm\sqrt z$

Comment: If the OP wanted to use Mathematica then he could simply have used it to directly plot the function, couldn't he?

Comment: Sadly, I need to find points such as Points of Inflection and Maximums and Minimums algebraically before graphing.

Comment: @AlexM. This is merely to back up the claim that the solution is symbolically intangible.

Comment: @John I'm afraid this particular function will not allow using an algebraic approach.

Comment: @AlexR So you suppose I should go ahead and use a graphing program and just graph it? By looking at the work you put into it I can see how there is no easy way to solve it algebraically

Comment: @John: No, the important thing for you to understand is that sometimes you know that some solutions are in some interval, but you cannot plot them precisely. Therefore, just sketch a reasonable shape of the graph, without knowing the exact location of the inflection points.

Comment: @AlexM. Awesome, you are a life saver, thank you very much!

Comment: But honestly, thank you all guys for the help, I would have gotten nowhere without your help. I am deeply grateful

Answer (score 1):

Just a sketch for $x>0$: this transcendental equation cannot be solved explicitly. Nevertheless, by putting it in the form $\tan x^2 = \frac 1 {2x^2}$ one notices that the graph of the left-hand side (LHS) is made of several disjoint branches, each one *increasing* continuously from $0$ to $\infty$, while the right-hand side (RHS) is *decreasing* from $\infty$ to $\frac 1 {8 \pi^2}$. As such, the LHS will intersect the RHS in as many points as branches the LHS has and these will be the inflection points. A similar analysis for $x<0$.

Comment: The $x<0$ analysis can be reduced by symmetry. No need for additional work.